# How to loop through array.reduce variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following array, which contains dates.

```
var arrs= ["2016/10/4", "2016/10/4", "2016/10/7", "2016/10/7", "2016/10/7"];
```

I am reducing this array to get count of same dates, so I am using following code,

```
var maps = arrs.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
    return prev;
}, {});
console.log(maps);
```

Now, the count is available for each unique dates as follows in browser console,

```
Object {2016/10/4: 2, 2016/10/7: 3}
```

I want to make json object for this reduce object.

```
[{
    date : 2016/10/4,
    value : 2
},
{
    date : 2016/10/7,
    value : 3
}]
```

How to get it, I am not able to get length or make forEach to maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After generating the object use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods to generate the required array.

```js
var arrs = ["2016/10/4", "2016/10/4", "2016/10/7", "2016/10/7", "2016/10/7"];

var maps = arrs.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

maps = Object.keys(maps) // get all property name 
  // iterate and generate eleemnt
  .map(function(k) {
    // generate prefered structure of array eleement
    return {
      date: k,
      value: maps[k]
    };
  });

console.log(maps);
```

Comment: Great, this is what I am looking for. Thanks Balan.

Comment: @Clara : glad to help you :)